# Five nines, four ￼, one bugged blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, unicode

One picture worth 1000 words:

[image: 4 obj characters at end of blog title]

The title of [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/09/22/five-nines-uptime) has four ￼   ([object replacement](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%BF%BC)) characters injected to it, which doesn't look good. It affects the blog title itself, the link to the blog, and the browser's address bar.

Can this please be removed? Worth to mention, the [podcast](https://player.simplecast.com/4f75b232-a011-4ff4-b0ea-1c7d9df62bcf?dark=false) caption isn't affected.

Comment: I wonder where those characters came from. They don't seem to have had a different 'value'. Copy/paste?

Comment: @Joachim object copied from Word/Excel/etc. (Most likely.)

Comment: probably a flame emoji or something flashy like that.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't think so, viewed it on my phone as well, which should have all emojis, still just the cryptic object replacement character. (Missing emoji would appear as blank rectangle afaik)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard, no it's my guess what should've been there. But it indeed is most likely a copy pasta action into a system or font that didn't support the original emoji.

Comment: Title fixed, "Show notes" still there.

Comment: I think those *are* the show notes?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek oh wait, you mean those are notes for the "Show"? But that's not a show. It's podcast episode, with real people, not actors. (Hopefully)

Comment: @Laurel what you mean by "I can't actually see the character on my device"? What you do see then? (Here in the bug report, blog itself is already fixed)

Comment: It [looks like a space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dQ40.png) to me, which made editing the post a bit tedious. (Didn't look at the blog but expect it wouldn't render there either before it was fixed.)

Comment: @Laurel huh, so weird. What browser/OS? :)

Comment: iOS, all browsers.

Comment: Yes, the byte sequence as posted here is 0xEF 0xBF 0xBC, corresponding to the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) sequence for [OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65526).

Answer (score 8):

This was fixed shortly after the bug report was submitted.

However, I would still like to hear what led to those characters added to the title, and hopefully something that can be done to prevent it from happening again.